# Make image appear half on screen, other half scroll to see

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

The idea for the website is that there is a video playing in the background that takes up the entire width and height of the browser when you go to it. Then you scroll down and get to rest of the content. So far I have the video part of it working. The part that is causing me trouble is a picture of an iphone that also needs to be included. About half of the phone is covering up a part of the video. The other half you need to scroll down to see (along with the rest of the content). I need the phone to 1. Always appear in that position, no matter the window size; and 2. Scale to be the same ratio of phone size to window size.

I've tried many things to get this functioning, it just hasn't seemed to work for me yet.

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $('#video').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });

            $(window).resize(function(){
                $('#video').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="video" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/SLTVLIjvdnw?HD=1;autoplay=1;controls=0;showinfo=0;" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div id="box">
        <img id="iphone" src="img/phone.png" alt="iPhone" />
    </div>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>
```

```
html, body {
border: 0px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

body {
overflow: hidden;
}

#test {
width:400px;
height:400px;
background-color:blue;
}

#box {
position:absolute;
max-width:280px;
left:10%;
top:380px;
}

#iphone {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The image noes not take up the full page. It is in front of the video. The image itself is only 150x250 px.

Comment: We really need to see code to help you out.

Comment: without code, we are having issues understanding your implementation

Comment: The test div is unimportant at this moment

Comment: use z-index to make the video appear over the image

Comment: The video I want to be in the background. The image just needs to always appear half in the browser and half out of it, so that it is appearing from the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure CSS solution, assuming I understood the problem correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/5aVZa/1/

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.video {
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.iphone {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -25%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working really well. except for some reason my video always appears in front of the iphone. I tried setting a z-index to no  avail.

Comment: Add `position: relative;` along with your `z-index` on `.iphone`: http://jsfiddle.net/5aVZa/2/

Comment: Nice. You're the bomb.